# Oracle 11g: ORA-00604 ORA-02429 when inserting record. Cannot insert in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dml

I've created a new table in my Oracle 11g database using the following script.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
  test_number       NUMBER,
  test_name         VARCHAR2(100),
  test_system       NUMBER,
  isEnabled         CHAR(1),
  createdby         NUMBER,
  created           DATE,
  modifiedby        NUMBER,
  modified          DATE,
  comments          VARCHAR2(150),
  hasAgenda         CHAR(1),
  hasValue          CHAR(1),
  resumee           VARCHAR2(50),
  images            VARCHAR2(100),
  hasOptions        CHAR(1),
  isRecorded        CHAR(1),
  isSaved           CHAR(1),
  valueType         VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Then, I tried to insert a record using the following script:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE
    (test_number, test_name, test_system, isEnabled, createdby,
    created, modifiedby, modified, comments, hasAgenda,
    hasValue, resumee, images, hasOptions, isRecorded,
    isSaved, valueType)
VALUES(
    1, 'name', 2, 'Y', 3,
    SYSDATE, 4, SYSDATE, 'obs', 'Y',
    'Y', 'resumee', 'images', 'Y', 'Y',
    'N', 'value'
);
```

When I run the insert statement, I recieve this error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key
```

I cannot figure out why I am receiving this error when no indexes or constraints are defined. There are no triggers associated with the table either.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any system level triggers? It seems so.

Comment: What keys and indexes do you have in this table?

Comment: This is a completely new table, I have not defined indexes or constraints yet, not even a PK. That's why I think this is a very strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Error `ORA-00604` is a common error that can sometimes be difficult to resolve. ORA-00604 occurs while processing a recursive SQL statement.

A recursive SQL statement is a statement that applies to internal dictionary tables (or your own tables inside a trigger).

So there should be a situation which triggered that access to internal directory tables.

You should firstly check for existing DDL or system triggers which may be affecting you.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM dba_triggers
 WHERE trigger_type NOT LIKE '% EACH ROW' AND trigger_type NOT LIKE 'INSTEAD OF';
```

Other causes can be invalid PL/SQL which get compiled, as result of a new row.

Since there are many possible reasons for the error, Oracle simply indicates which is the next error in the stack.

If you have access to your server, you may consider to trace your session:

```
ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE=TRUE;

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE
    (test_number, test_name, test_system, isEnabled, createdby,
    created, modifiedby, modified, comments, hasAgenda,
    hasValue, resumee, images, hasOptions, isRecorded,
    isSaved, valueType)
VALUES(
    1, 'name', 2, 'Y', 3,
    SYSDATE, 4, SYSDATE, 'obs', 'Y',
    'Y', 'resumee', 'images', 'Y', 'Y',
    'N', 'value'
);

ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE=FALSE;
```

You can identify your trace file under your diag directory  **$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/<db_name>/<instace_name>/trace** with following name:

```
SELECT LOWER(SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'instance_name')) || '_ora_' || p.spid || '.trc' AS trace_file
  FROM v$session s, v$process p
 WHERE s.paddr = p.addr AND s.audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');
```

Take a look at that file you may find where error come from.